# Java/stream - instead of summing it sets just the first value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm having big problem with making Java stream work the way I want it to. I have a class with fields: title(string), value(BigDecimal). I get objects of this class in a form of list. Titles on the list are not unique, and I want to get list where titles ARE unique, and values for the same titles(of input list) are summed.

So I make something like:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> groupedAndSummed = inputList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyClass::getTitle, 
    Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, MyClass::getValue, BigDecimal::add)));
```

From what I found out - such code should return Map where titles are keys(so they are unique), values are values, but for the same keys they are summed. I tried also:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> groupedAndSummed = inputList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyClass::getTitle, MyClass::getValue, BigDecimal::add));
```

Which from my point of view should do the same thing. So, once again, I get list with objects, that can have the same titles. I want to get list with objects where titles are unique, and for initial objects with the same titles I want to make sum of values of duplicates. I've searched for solutions, and the way I'm doing it should work, but it doesn't. I get list of objects with distinct titles, but theirs values are not summed. It's always simply first value to be summed, from the all that should be summed, for that title. I dont know where I'm doing something wrong. When I do it manually it works, I use something like

```
sum = sum.add(object.getValue());
```

And the sums are ok after whole loop. The problem is, that I'm looking for automatic way to do it, no some nested loops in loops checking suspicious conditions. I would like it to work with stream. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your first snippet works fine (not counting the typos, such as `gruppingBy` and `MyClass:getValue`).

Comment: The second snippet also works fine. Perhaps you have an issue in `MyClass`.

Comment: Well, it does not work in my application, and I'm getting really mad. Does it make a difference that the initial objects are objects retrieved from database using JPA, and they are detached by entity manager?

Comment: I have no idea, but there must be a difference between the code you posted and the actual code you are running, and the error lies within that difference.

Comment: The code I posted is the same(I changed class name, but the syntax is basically identical), and we tried writing it by 2 people on 2 different computers. If it works for you I belive that there is really something wrong with initial Class. It's entitiy class, it uses inheritance, it's retrived and then detached by entity manager. I still dont see why it should be a problem, I'm creating completely new Map using these values, perhaps there is something in stream that I dont yet understand.

Comment: What happens if instead of reducing (in your first sample), you collect to a `List<BigDecimal>` instead ? Do you obtain singletonLists ?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be possible you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?